# Using the id selector with other selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to know, what does the following CSS mean?

```
.twoCol #sidebar
```

Isn't `#sidebar` alone enough? What does this line of CSS actually select?

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accessing the element with the id `sidebar` within any element that uses the `twoCol` class.

`#sidebar` *is* enough on its own really, as it's an ID, but this is a little more semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't #sidebar alone is enough?

Yes. An `id` *should* be unique. *(and it will be, unless you're dealing with poor quality HTML)*

The `.twoCol` prefix is not optimal because it's adding redundant information.

This is comically demonstrated here: http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php

A more complete article, which isn't specific to this case, but a good and relevant read nonetheless:

http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Comment: I'm not sure that it's "useless" really.. Sometimes it can be useful if you're dealing with a large css file and elements are grouped logically. Of course, this can also lead to horrendous misuse.

Answer (score 1):

[Demian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351732/dumb-css-question/6351745#6351745) and [thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351732/dumb-css-question/6351760#6351760) are largely correct, but this does have a conditional use:

If you have several templates and sometimes `#sidebar` occurs in `.twoCol`, but sometimes it occurs somewhere else - you can target that specific template without including another CSS file.

In this case, it makes more sense to assign a class to the `<html>`, `<body>`, or template wrapper, but I just thought I'd point out that it's not *strictly* useless.

Comment: +1 for truth, but I really hate it when what you described is done. (the "several templates" thing)